# Importerror from runserver command

Tags: python, django

(Sorry I'm new at this so I apologize if the question isn't worded well)

I tried to run `python manage.py runserver` after setting up for a project without error, however it wasn't successful and it displayed the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'`.

In response to the error, I tried to use use a separate command to import: `from django.utils.encoding import python_unicode_compatible`
. However, this gave an error as well: `from: can't read /var/mail/django.utils.encoding`.

Might anyone know what this error means and what I may do to fix it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

instead of

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

Comment: It resulted in a similar error sadly: `from: can't read /var/mail/django.utils.six`. Not sure if this is crucial info, but I'm working in a mac terminal instead of writing a python script - would that make a difference? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: That's a separate problem; you need this in your Python file, not in your shell.